# Parsing a string to DateTime, formatting, then back to string - C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm pulling a date/time from a MS SQL Server 2008 db and trying to format the date to show just the date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format.

The data in the DB looks like this:

```
2011-05-04 15:50:00.000
```

The unformatted string when displayed appears as this:

```
5/25/2011 8:47:00 AM
```

Yet this code fails when I try to parse it to the correct format:

```
DateTime dateA = DateTime.ParseExact(curShopDate, "ddMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
curShopDate = dateA.ToString();
```

I also tried this code, trying to split just the date portion away from the time:

```
string[] stringA = curShopDate.Split(' ');
DateTime dateA = DateTime.ParseExact(stringA[0], "ddMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
curShopDate = dateA.ToString();
```

Both versions crashed with an "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." error.

Comment: the datetime examples are from different records.  I didn't have the energy to dig through thousands of unsorted fields in the DB to find matching examples.

Comment: And....I'm stupid apparently.  Solved it myself by pulling my head out of my arse and realizing it's already formatted and just stripping the time out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with your format parameter. Your string is not in the `ddMMyyyy` format, it's in the `M/dd/yyyy` format:

```
string curShopDate = "5/25/2011 8:47:00 AM";
DateTime dateA = DateTime.ParseExact(curShopDate.Split(' ')[0], "M/dd/yyyy",
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You could also parse the string without stripping the time from the date:

```
string curShopDate = "5/25/2011 8:47:00 AM";
DateTime dateA = DateTime.ParseExact(curShopDate, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

> The DateTime.ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider) method parses
>   the string representation of a date, which must be in the format
>   defined by the format parameter. It also requires that the  and
>    elements of the string representation of a date and time appear
>   in the order specified by format, and that s have no white space other
>   than that permitted by format.

So, if I'm reading that correctly, you specified the format as "ddMMyyyy" but your string is in "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt". Try either changing your format to "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt" or switch to DateTime.TryParse().

Answer (score 0):

If you use ParseExact, then you must specify the exact format: `"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"`, which matches your date string `"5/25/2011 8:47:00 AM"`.

You can take the date component of a date/time with:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dateOnly = dateTime.Date;
```